# What is my 'permanent residence address' when I have no 'permanent' residency anywhere in the world and no place in my home country?

Tags: residency

I have not lived in my 'home' country (my country of birth) for more than 9 years now and I have rarely visited it during all these years. And ever since I have lived in four different countries, always under a 'temporary residence permit'.

For the past three years I have stayed in the same country in Europe and still have a 'temporary residence permit'.

It happens very often that I am asked to provide my **permanent address** in legal documents. When I provide my address in the EU country where I have lived for the past three years, nobody accepts it and they all ask me to provide my ***PERMANENT*** (yes, they really like to emphasize that word) address in my home country. The problem is that I have **none**, I haven't lived there for over 9 years and I have no place of my own there, never had. I used to provide my latest place of residence there where I lived with my parents. But that has also become irrelevant now, as my parents have gone separate paths and don't even live there anymore and one of them has even moved out of that country.

So... What is my permanent address? What can I use?

Comment: I usually put the house of a parent or family member. I'm in the same situation as you.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to vary a lot depending on context and jurisdiction.

In the UK you can use the address where you usually reside, even if it's rented accommodation with no security of tenure and even if you are a person with only a temporary residence permit.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me in Hong Kong, when opening a bank account. The first bank I talked to really really wanted me to furnish a permanent address in my country of citizenship. Like you, I don't have one. But one of my passports, and my French ID card mentioned an address in France - a place I had sold since.

The first bank refused that. They wanted something more trustworthy. No clue what would have counted as trustworthy: they just said no. But I guess they wanted a receipt for utilities or something. Which obviously I couldn't provide. So I went to another bank, and they were fine with my passport and ID card.

If you have a national ID card and/or passport that mention an old address, try and use that. Or if you're still in touch with the parents, try to get a utility bill copy.