# What is my country of permanent residence for UK visa purposes?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa, uk-visa, legal

I am filling out a UK student visa application, and it asks for my "country of permanent residence," but it does not provide a definition for this term.

I currently reside outside of my country of citizenship on a "temporary residence permit", which will expire before I leave the UK. However, I am eligible to extend this permit to a date later than when I will be departing the UK. Furthermore, I am eligible to apply for citizenship by registration in my current country of residence, although I have not yet done so. I have no home address in my country of citizenship.

Can I declare my current country of residence as my "country of permanent residence" and apply from here, or will I have problems (given that my visa expires before my date of departure from the UK)? I can explain on the application that the visa can be renewed beyond the date that I will be departing the UK, that I am eligible for citizenship here, etc...

A similar question was asked: [What is my 'permanent residence address' when I have no 'permanent' residency anywhere in the world and no place in my home country?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13766/what-is-my-permanent-residence-address-when-i-have-no-permanent-residency-an) but refers to general legal documents and banking, rather than UK-specific visa definitions & regulations.

Comment: Is there any chance of extending your current residence permission before applying for the student visa?  The lack of a place to return to at the end of the proposed stay in the UK could be a problem.  Of course, you can always return to your country of citizenship, but you seem to have few ties there, nor an actual intention to return.  Your application will be much stronger if you can show permission to return to your country of residence, as well as an intention to do so and demonstrable ties implying that your intention will not change.

Comment: Just put your passport country unless you actually have Permanent Residence somewhere. That is because i) it's factually true, even if (like me) you don't want to live in your PP country again and ii) the UK really does not like people who wish to stay longer than their visa length even if you can/will apply to stay. As a UK student, you are expected to ONLY be in the UK to study and then to leave immediately (as I was told when I was one, "you just study here, you do NOT live here")

Comment: la femme cosmique is correct. They mean the place that would have to legally reside in if you suddenly had no visa or permit to live anywhere permanently (no matter what you might qualify for now or at some later point in time). From your description, that's your country of citizenship.

Comment: Many thanks! Does this mean that I would need to fly back to my country of citizenship (despite not living there) to apply?

Comment: Normally it's just your passport country, but you can submit your application anywhere. They just want a "permanent address" to be listed. I submitted application to German universities when I was studying somewhere outside of my home country.